# Can I ground a receptacle without a ground coming from the power?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, grounding

So I am adding new receptacles to my house that was built in the 50’s so some of the wiring only has a hot and a neutral with no ground but at one point the kitchen was remodeled and I noticed that the line cables still don’t have a ground but the load cables do. Is it okay to pigtail 3 grounds without a ground coming from the power? So one to the receptacle, one to the metal box and another with load cables.[image]

Comment: I believe adding/retrofitting a ground wire is approved, it is the only wire you can do this.  You can also use GFCI receptacles/outlets with the no equipment ground label on them for safety instead.

Comment: I would recommend running a seperate green or bare copper wire back to your main entrance (where all the grounds connect) to each of the plugs that need a ground. To my knowledge this is acceptable via NEC.  (National Electric Code).

Comment: How hard would it be to get a wire from the boxes in question back to somewhere on your grounding electrode system?

Answer (score 3):

Connecting an "island of grounds" (connected to each other not to the panel) would only be bad.  It would mean that if any one appliance had a ground fault (hot leaked to ground) internally, this would cause all the grounds on all the appliances would be energized - in other words it would "share the pain" and none of the benefit.  Indeed this is a code violation.

In order to extend this circuit, a proper ground is mandatory.  NEC 406.4(A)-(C).

You absolutely are allowed to retrofit a ground according to the rules in 250.130, which allow running a properly sized ground wire to:

- any other junction box that has a properly sized ground wire back to the panel
- any junction box that has non-flex metal conduit back to the panel
- anywhere along the Grounding Electrode Conductor (GEC) which is the thick bare wire running from your panel to ground rods, and is the ultimate actual grounding for your house.
- The panel itself, of course.

Comment: In one of these 1950s houses with no ground is it acceptable to GFCI protect various circuits, put in modern receptacles and put on a sticker stating GFCI protected but no ground? I know someone in that position and would like to know if that is acceptable?

Comment: @Jim that only works for receptacle *replacements* per 406.4(D), and is not allowed for circuit extensions.

Answer (score 0):

##### Think outside the box

If your house is like my 1950s house with lots of ungrounded receptacles and metal boxes, you *may* find that you actually have ground wires *behind* the boxes. I have replaced many ungrounded receptacle with grounded receptacles and fully expected to have to install some GFCI/receptacle-in-lieu-of-grounding. But I haven't had to do that. Instead I have found in each case that there was a ground wire either inside the box (super easy) or **outside the box**. Yes, really. A ground wire wrapped around a screw or clamp outside the box, in the wall. Or even just hanging there.

Three things to check:

- Neutral to ground continuity

With the circuit off, use a multimeter to check continuity between the line-side neutral wire and the metal box. If you get continuity then that should mean a proper ground is in there somewhere, and grounding the receptacle to the box (automatic with a better quality receptacle, or a wire from receptacle ground screw to the box)

- Armored Cable

Certain types of armored cable (BX, not sure what else) are effective grounds if installed properly.

- Ground wires in the panel

If you can safely check the panel (i.e., a modern panel and not the little old 1950s fuse boxes) and see that the relevant cables have ground wires, then the ground wires are likely *outside the boxes*. In which case ideally you should remove the boxes, route the ground wires into the boxes and attach with a proper ground screw.

Comment: That is the way it was done and they even saved money by using a size smaller for the ground wire which was attached to the box. At that time three prong receptacles were not that common.